# Change column value depending on other columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
chrom position ref var normal_reads1 normal_reads2 normal_var_freq normal_gt tumor_reads1 tumor_reads2 tumor_var_freq tumor_gt somatic_status variant_p_value somatic_p_value
1    2L    13048   A   T            32            23           41.82         W           17            6          26.09        W       Germline    7.507123e-11       0.9437542
2    2L    16467   G   A             0            43          100.00         A            0           24         100.00        A           <NA>    6.674261e-40       1.0000000
3    2L    20682   T   A            32            14           30.43         W           14            6          30.00        W       Germline    1.746726e-07       0.6223244
4    2L    25727   T   G            52            22           29.73         K           16            4          20.00        K       Germline    2.000049e-09       0.8758070
5    2L    25729   A   T            49            23           31.94         W           16            4          20.00        W       Germline    7.938282e-10       0.9092970
6    2L    25741   T   C            45            28           38.36         Y           15            6          28.57        Y       Germline    1.497796e-12       0.8604958
```

I'm trying to change to value of the `somatic_status` col to "ROH" if both `normal_var_freq` and `tumor_var_freq` are `> 90`

Here's what I've tried:

```
snps <- within(snps, somatic_status[normal_var_freq > 90 & tumor_var_freq > 90] <- 'ROH')
```

but I get the error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, normal_var_freq > 90 & tumor_var_freq >  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: convert the `somatic_status` column to `character` and don't use `within` to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can the `factor` to `character` `class` before assigning the values to 'ROH' based on the logical vector ('i1')

```
i1 <- with(snps, normal_var_freq > 90 & tumor_var_freq > 90)
snps$somatic_status <- as.character(snps$somatic_status)
snps$somatic_status[i1] <- "ROH"
```

---

or add a new `level` to the column if we don't want to convert the `factor` column to `character` before changing some of the elements to a new value

```
levels(snps$somatic_status) <- c(levels(snps$somatic_status), "ROH")
snps$somatic_status[i1] <- "ROH"
```

---

Regarding the usage of `within`, it is a useful function for creating new variables or updates old variables, but the assigning a subset of values to new value is not recommended